# Gearbox failure

Tags: vw, transmission, audi

Audi A3 1.4 TFSI, 45,000 miles on the clock.

Out of nowhere, I got a gearbox malfunction, you can continue driving.

P084100 code

The car will not drive.

I have had this diagnosed with the following errors.

Any ideas on a potential cause of action.

[image]

Comment: So what was the code or codes? that may help pinpoint a particular sensor or component.

Comment: P084100, its in the image

Comment: "There may be one or more causes for the P0841 code. One may be a faulty electronic pressure control solenoid. Another could be that there is something wrong with your transmission fluid pressure sensor, or that your vehicle has hydraulic blockages inside the internal transmission fluid passages. You may also have low transmission fluid, dirty or contaminated transmission fluid, mechanical internal transmission failures. A faulty PCM or transmission control module is rare but possible." It needs a professional diagnosis.

Comment: https://www.yourmechanic.com/article/p0841-obd-ii-trouble-code-transmission-fluid-pressure-sensor-switch-a-circuit-range-performance-by-valerie-johnston

Answer (score 1):

Incase this is useful for the next person.

The car had done about 44,000 miles, so I wasn't expecting gearbox issues.

Apparently it is a common problem in DSG 7 units.

I sent the mechatronics unit to a company called ECU testing, a mechanic was able to take it out and sent it off to them. It cost £400.00 including VAT for a rebuild of the unit which comes with an unlimited mileage warranty. It some back within a week and has since been fitted and the car drives.

I am suspecting, after talking to an experienced mechanic, it could have been a cracked hydraulic accumulator, which would have been cheaper to fix, however, ECU testing fix this and complete the rebuild.

Comment: Are you the same person who posted the question?